# Save the state of ng-src in Angualr.js

Tags: angularjs, local-storage

I am trying to make a saveable header image for an application in Angular.js, so far I have this code, also available as a Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YAFsJvekc838YI6RHLFA?p=preview):

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.bannerState = false;

  $scope.changeHeader = function () {
    $scope.bannerState = true;
  };

  $scope.currentImage = 0;

  $scope.nextButton = function () {
    if ($scope.bannerState) {
      $scope.currentImage++;
    }
    if ($scope.currentImage > ($scope.bannerImages.length - 1)) {
      $scope.currentImage = 0;
    }
  };

  $scope.previousButton = function () {
    if ($scope.bannerState) {
      $scope.currentImage--;
    }
    if ($scope.currentImage < 0) {
      $scope.currentImage = ($scope.bannerImages.length - 1);
    }
  };

  $scope.setHeader = function () {
    $scope.bannerState = false;
  };

  $scope.bannerImages = [
    {
      src: "http://yaocho-digital.com/portfolio/content/threadme1.png"
    },
    {
      src: "http://yaocho-digital.com/portfolio/content/threadme2.png"
    },
    {
      src: "http://yaocho-digital.com/portfolio/content/threadme3.png"
    }
  ];
});
```

I have no idea how to store this in an object so that I can go away from the page and come back and it is there! Please help!

JP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HTML 5 local storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Storage#Local_and_session_storage) would be an option to store the state locally.

I modified your `app.js` file:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.bannerState = false;

  $scope.changeHeader = function () {
    $scope.bannerState = true;
  };

  $scope.currentImage = window.localStorage.getItem("bannerImage") | 0;

  $scope.nextButton = function () {
    if ($scope.bannerState) {
      $scope.currentImage++;
    }
    if ($scope.currentImage > ($scope.bannerImages.length - 1)) {
      $scope.currentImage = 0;
    }
  };

  $scope.previousButton = function () {
    if ($scope.bannerState) {
      $scope.currentImage--;
    }
    if ($scope.currentImage < 0) {
      $scope.currentImage = ($scope.bannerImages.length - 1);
    }
  };

  $scope.setHeader = function () {
    window.localStorage.setItem("bannerImage", $scope.currentImage);
    $scope.bannerState = false;
  };

  $scope.bannerImages = [
    {
      src: "http://yaocho-digital.com/portfolio/content/threadme1.png"
    },
    {
      src: "http://yaocho-digital.com/portfolio/content/threadme2.png"
    },
    {
      src: "http://yaocho-digital.com/portfolio/content/threadme3.png"
    }
  ];
});
```

Comment: That is perfect. No extra plugins, or $rootScope clogging! Why thank you, sir!

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in $rootScope - so long as your page doesn't reset, you'll be good